# cannot access class org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils with java 17 ! How to open a package of unknown module?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-17

I want to integrate spring(spring boot 2.7.3)  with JavaFx application implement on java17 and I got the following issue ;

```
class com.XXX$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$637d19c4 (in module com.xxx) cannot access class 
org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils (in unnamed module @0x2d950574) because module
com.xxx does not read unnamed module @0x2d950574
```

Any Help ?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with Java 17 and solved it by adding to my open module in modules-info.java, the following:

```
    requires spring.core;
    requires spring.beans;
```

Using Spring Framework 6, Spring Boot 3.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the JVM argument `--add-reads=com.xxx=ALL-UNNAMED`

Answer (score 1):

On Java 19, I also had simmilliar problem:

`(in module com.xxx) cannot access class  org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils (in unnamed module @0x2d950574) because module com.xxx does not read unnamed module @0x2d950574`

Please have a look on `module com.xxx` in above message. As a solution you can add  VM argument:

`--add-reads com.xxx=ALL-UNNAMED`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a vm argument `--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM`

If it's working fine, you can then specify only modules raising the issue.